# how to invert the intersect point in tikz

Tags: circuitikz

When I yscale the op amp in circuitikz , the intersect node shifts up. How will I negate the intersect point.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \def\Ba{0,0.5}
    \draw
        (\Ba)node[ground]{}to[R,l=$R_{2}$,-*]++(0,2)node(vx){}--++(0,1)node[op amp,yscale=-1, anchor=-](a1){}
        (vx-|a1.out)node(vo){}
        (vx)to[R,l=$R_{1}$]++(vo)--(a1.out)to[short,-*](a1.out)
        (a1.+)to[short,-o]++(-0.5,0)node[left]{$v_{in}$}
        (a1.out)to[short,-o]++(0.5,0)node[right]{$v_{out}$}
        ;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I end up getting a circuit that looks like this.

[image]

So I use `let` command to get the co-ordinates and got the following circuit.

[image]

Is there is any way by which I can negate the coordinates without the use of let command to bring the intersect point mirrored in opposite direction

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \def\Ba{0,0.5}
    \draw
        (\Ba)node[ground]{}to[R,l=$R_{2}$,-*]++(0,2)node(vx){}--++(0,1)node[op amp,yscale=-1, anchor=-](a1){}
        %(vx-|a1.out)node[scale=-1](vo){}
        let \p1=(vx),\p2=(a1.out) in 
        (vx)to[R,l=$R_{1}$]++(\x2,\x1)--(a1.out)to[short,-*](a1.out)
        (a1.+)to[short,-o]++(-0.5,0)node[left]{$v_{in}$}
        (a1.out)to[short,-o]++(0.5,0)node[right]{$v_{out}$}
        ;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: I don't quite understand, which is the "intersect node"? And what do you mean by "negate" here?

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example that loads all necessary classes, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only rewrite your MWE to me more logical defined coordinates of connection points:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (Ba) at (0,0.5);
\draw
    (Ba)    node[ground]{}      to[R,l=$R_{2}$,-*] ++ (0,2)
            coordinate (vx)     -- ++ (0,1)
            node[op amp,yscale=-1, anchor=-] (a1) {}
    (a1.out)    -- ++ (0.5,0) coordinate (vo)
                to[short,-o] ++ (0.5,0) node[right] {$v_{\mathit{out}}$}
    (vx)    to[R,l=$R_{1}$]     (vx -| vo) 
            to[short,-*] (vo)
    (a1.+) to[short,-o] ++ (-0.5,0) node[left] {$v_{\mathit{in}}$}
    (a1.out) 
    ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Please see, if with this code you can reproduce your problem.

Comment: Can I know the reason, why my code failed? Is it due to the use of coordinates that has resolved the problem?

Comment: @Narashimaraja, frankly said, I don't know. To me was simpler to redefine coordinates of elements. Main difference is that I for `R_1` use fixed coordinates and you relative (probably on wrong way).

Comment: Thank you. Now I realized my mistake in the code. I used relative positioning. Thanks